# selecting a row only if it satisfies another criteria for the similar row

Tags: sql, oracle

Table orders

```
Status_id Order_number 
100        ord1 
200        ord2 
100        ord3 
300        ord2 
100        Ord4 
400        ord2 
200        ord1
200        ord3
```

I need all the orders that are with the `Status_id=100` or `200` BUT if the same orders have `Status_id=400`, it should not be selected. 
In the example above, `ord1`,`ord3`, `ord4` should be selected. But `Ord2` should not be selected as it is also with `status_id=400`.

Comment: Do you need to show only the `order_number`, or do you need to show the entire row (that is, including `status_id`) for the orders that meet your requirements?

Comment: Actual requirement is to show entire row including status_id, Order_number, order_date, account_number etc.  As an alternate what I did is collected the order_number from above query and then re-queried the table to get all the information.  For my knowledge if you have a simpler solution, will be great. Thanks Mathguy.

Comment: That is a very inefficient way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of problem that is readily solved with `group by` and `having`:

```
select order_number
from orders
group by order_number
having sum(case when status in (100, 200) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status = 400 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: @DevadasWagle . . . As the OP, you can accept whichever answer you like.  I'm curious though why you unaccepted this answer, which seems the most direct answer to the question you asked.

Comment: Gordon - I am not the OP, and hopefully the OP will give you his or her answer. However, you may want to look at the Comments below the original post. You will see that I asked for clarification, which the OP provided (in a Comment instead of editing the post itself). I wrote my answer only after the OP provided the clarification. Perhaps that answers your question.

Comment: @mathguy . . . That makes sense.  People should learn how to ask questions.

Comment: Agreed. Having to deal with people who don't ask their questions in the best possible way, I often ask follow-up questions while others are writing solutions. (Both here and on OTN.) I find it is good practice for how I would communicate with the business managers who bring their problems to IT - if I ever worked in the field. (I don't and I will not - I am retired, from other fields; it is still fun to imagine what the discussion would be like, with a business analyst or such.) I do help people in real life too, the discussions are similar.

Comment: Oops! I am still getting used to this stack overflow.  Both the Answers are correct for my original post!  I did not realize that selecting one  deselects the other.  While asking the question at first I did not realize that the solution  given would not work when I use more columns in the select clause.

Comment: @DevadasWagle . . . It is okay.  You can accept mathguy's answer.  I was only asking because I thought this was a concise and accurate answer to question.  I understand now that his is more helpful because of the clarification in the comment, which I'm guessing was after I answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the full details of every row, rather than just the order numbers, then you need to use analytic functions rather than aggregates; in this case, a conditional analytic count on rows where `test_data=400`.

```
with
     test_data ( status_id, order_number ) as (
       select 100, 'ord1' from dual union all 
       select 200, 'ord2' from dual union all  
       select 100, 'ord3' from dual union all 
       select 300, 'ord2' from dual union all 
       select 100, 'ord4' from dual union all 
       select 400, 'ord2' from dual union all 
       select 200, 'ord1' from dual union all 
       select 200, 'ord3' from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the query); SQL query begins below this line
select   status_id, order_number
from     ( select status_id, order_number,
                  count(case when status_id = 400 then 1 end)
                             over (partition by order_number) as st_400_cnt
           from   test_data
         )
where    status_id in (100, 200)
  and    st_400_cnt = 0
order by order_number, status_id   --  if needed
;

STATUS_ID ORDER_NUMBER
--------- ------------
      100 ord1
      200 ord1
      100 ord3
      200 ord3
      100 ord4

5 rows selected.
```